# Open mysql only to localhost and a particular address

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, mysql, iptables

**My config**: ubuntu server 9 and msyql 5

```
my.cnf = bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

my iptables script =

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 99.88.77.66 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

I can connect from any place to mysql, not only that IP. 
I made a iptables-save , /etc/init.d/netwokring restart... but I still can connect from any IP, any clue ?

Comment: Perhaps you have a rule which is passing the packet from earlier in your ruleset.  Can you post iptables -L?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule allows connections from 99.88.77.66, it does not prevent connections from somewhere else. To do that, you should have a rule that defaults to DROP for all incoming connections

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

and then proceeds to allow only those you explicitly want to. Alternatively, you can close port 3306 specifically for all clients that are not 99.88.77.66

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s ! 99.88.77.66 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2):

That rule *allows* traffic from a particular IP to port 3306/tcp. You need later rule (or default policy) to drop all other traffic to that port, because the default iptables policy is to allow everything.

Comment: Specifically: `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s ! 99.88.77.66 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j DROP`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your default policy of iptables is allow for all input traffic. this would allow a connection from any ip. change this policy to drop:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```